# Markdown on Gitea

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, repository, markdown

Situation:

I'm using VSCode to write some Markdown document and upload it to Gitea.
I can upload everything just fine.

Whenever I use the VSCode Open Preview feature, everything works as intended, but as soon as it's up on my Git, it only works partially.

for example:

```
[![Teamviewer](./Ressourcen/Images/Teamviewer.png)](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/windows/?pid=google.tv_ex_sl2.s.de&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIrO63uNr53QIVDdOyCh1shwOuEAAYASABEgJXv_D_BwE "Teamviewer Downloadpage") 
 <br>
[<span style="color:cyan">**Teamviewer**</span>](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/windows/?pid=google.tv_ex_sl2.s.de&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIrO63uNr53QIVDdOyCh1shwOuEAAYASABEgJXv_D_BwE "Teamviewer Downloadpage")
```

Now if I click on the picture in VSC it opens up the link.
On Gitea it only opens the picture itself.

the `<span style="color=cyan">some tet </span>` part isn't working either, which is a shame really, because I'd love to add some color to my documents.

FYI 
The `(./Ressourcen/Images/Teamviewer.png)` does exist on the Git.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different markdown engines treat edge-cases like this differently. See e.g. https://commonmark.org for an explanation.

Also, most platforms (apparently including Gitea), post-process the generated HTML and sanitize it to remove `style` attributes etc. because they want a uniform style.

Comment: Just did! Thanks again! :)